# Creating neighbors, area and perimeter in spatial econometrics using R

Tags: arcgis-desktop, r, spatial-statistics

I’m working on a `spatial cross section model` with `R-programming-language`. I’m running these codes which refers to `anselin data` (spatial_columbus) in `spdep` package. I found them from these links:

[Main Page for more information](https://sites.google.com/site/econometricsacademy/econometrics-models/spatial-econometrics)

[Dataset](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0BwogTI8d6EEiZVdBSlgwdmFjTUk/edit?pli=1)

```
library(spdep)# Loading required package: sp &Loading required package: Matrix
data(Columbus)
mydata<-columbus
attach(mydata)
y<-cbind(CRIME)
 x<-cbind(INC,HOVAL)
xy<-cbind(mydata$X, mydata$Y)
neighbors<-col.gal.nb
coords<-coords
summary(neighbors)
```

When I used these codes for data (columbus) in `spdep` package, everything is fine, but when I want apply them to my data (human capital index) I’m not able to define `neighborhood` for my data . My problem is in this line `( neighbor<-col.gal.nb)`. it’s the neighbors list from an original `GAL-format file` and it’s a pre-defined file . I don’t know any codes for creating neighbors to my data and I think my data framework is different from spatial Columbus data framework (There is `AREA`, `PERIMETER`,`ID` and `polyID` columns that I don’t have these columns in my data framework).

The help link for `col.gal.nb` is here (you can open this link in R environment after above codes)

```
http://127.0.0.1:20991/library/spdep/html/columbus.html
```

**My questions are here:**

1. How can I use `ArcGIS`  to create `AREA` and `PERIMETER` to my data file? I have some counties as samples. Are any easier solution for finding these values or I should only use `ArcGIS` for this purpose? (In sample codes the author used `ArcGIS` to calculating these values).
2. Which code pack can I use to creating neighbors based on contiguity and distance in `R`?
   My dependent variable is `HCI`and `Y` is `latitude`, `X` is `longitude` and other variables are independent variables.

My data set framework : http://www.mediafire.com/view/lf43qm1h5ptztt6/spatial_columbus.csv

Pre-defined framework : http://www.mediafire.com/view/ml76tbrf6p69vkf/human_capital_index.csv

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It would be very helpful for you to read up on some R basics, particularity pertaining to sp class objects. A very good starting point would be Bivand's [ASDAR](http://www.asdar-book.org/) book and the [sp vignette](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/sp/vignettes/intro_sp.pdf). Here are some other related [R spatial analysis](http://www.bias-project.org.uk/ASDARcourse/) introductory material.

As to your problem at hand. For one, you can easily create a variety of spatial weights matrices in R using the spdep package. If you are working with polygons then you want to use n-neighbor contingency and not distance. It is also quite unnecessary to use ArcGIS to calculate area and perimeter. I would however, highly recommend projecting your data into a "distance based" projection which can be accomplished using "spTransform" (requiring both sp and rgdal). You can use the "readOGR" function in rgdal to read a polygon shapefile. Here are examples that demonstrate some solutions to your questions:

```
    # Add packages and example data
    require(sp)
    require(spdep)
    require(rgdal)

    eire <- readOGR(system.file("etc/shapes", package="spdep")[1], "eire")
        class(eire)
          plot( eire )

    # Create spatial weights matrix from polygon object
    knn <- knn2nb(knearneigh(coordinates(eire), k=4))
      all.linked <- max(unlist(nbdists(knn, coordinates(eire))))
        nb <- dnearneigh(coordinates(eire), 0, all.linked)
          colW <- nb2listw(nb, style="W")

    # Plot neighbor contingency 
    par(mfrow=c(1,2))
      plot(eire, border="grey")
        plot(nb, coordinates(eire), add=TRUE)
          box()
            title("All neighbors (kNN=n-1)")
      plot(eire, border="grey")
        plot(knn, coordinates(eire), add=TRUE)
          box()
            title("Neighbor contingency (kNN=4)")       

    # Calculate polygon(s) area   
    sapply(slot(eire, "polygons"), slot, "area")

    # Calculate polygon(s) perimeter 
    perimeter <- function(x) {
      p <- vector()
          for(i in 1:length(x)) {
           px <- as(x[i,], "SpatialLines")
           p <- append(p, LineLength(as.matrix(coordinates(px)[[1]][[1]])))
          }
        return( p )
      }  
    perimeter(eire)
```